# AngularJs redirect to route not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to redirect to another route after an event, but it shows only url change (http://localhost:8000/login changed to http://localhost:8000/login#/home). I want to change it to http://localhost:8000/home#, but I can not figure out how to do that. And my route for this url not working.

`app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('laravel', ['ngRoute'])
        .constant('API_URL', 'http://localhost:8000/')
        .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

            $routeProvider
            .when('/login', {

                controller: 'authController',
                templateUrl: 'resources/views/auth/login.blade.php',
            })
            .when('/home', {

                templateUrl : "resources/views/home.bade.php",
                controller : 'homeController'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/',
            });
        });
```

`auth.js`, containing my `authController`:

```
app.controller('authController', function ( $scope, $http, $location, API_URL){

    $scope.login = function(){

        var url = API_URL + "login";

        $http.post(url, $scope.file).success(function (response) {
        console.log("coming in homepage!!");
            // sessionStorage.setItem('user', $scope.user);
            $location.path('/home');
        });
    }
});
```

The above code just converts the URL http://localhost:8000/login to http://localhost:8000/login#/home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got it.**
**If you configure $location to use html5Mode (history.pushState), you need to specify the base URL for the application with a  tag or configure $locationProvider to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with requireBase:false to $locationProvider.html5Mode():**

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({ enabled: true,  requireBase: false});
//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //if we want to remove html5mode requirebase.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this i guess

```
$location.path('/home').replace();
```

You can check [API doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) for $location.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have already tried and result was same.